# Is there a way to view blocks as "code bubbles" in Sublime Text 3 or Atom?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I am looking for a way to view only a single block of code at a time. Right now, for instance, I have to work on a fairly big Javascript function in a decent-sized file, and I want to isolate just the function and view it in its own window - a sort of anti-distraction mode.

Is there a plugin that can do this?

Comment: http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-code-folding/

Comment: @DavidPostill that's what I've been using, but I want something that puts a "harder" limit on where I can browse/edit. If I fold a code block, it's relatively easy to Cmd+backspace it by accident.

Comment: This functionality is known in Emacs as "narrowing". Having switched to Vim a few years after posting this question, I now use the plugin `chrisbra/NrrwRgn` to provide this functionality.

Comment: You could convert that comment into a proper answer ...

Comment: It's not an answer to the question posed, though.